# c++11 regex and '[' escape

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, escaping

## My Problem

I have this problem i don't really understand:
i wanted to create a std::basic_regex matching `n+ '['` like this:

```
[...]
std::basic_regex("[+");
[...]
```

but well `'['` has not be escaped, so i get this exception (which is logic):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
```

Then I tried to repair my mistake by escaping the `'['` like this:

```
[...]
std::basic_regex("\\[+");
[...]
```

And there I don't know why but i still got the throwing exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
```

## So?

Anyone has this same error? or am i doing something wrong?

## Edit:

Forgot to put my g++ version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: try this `"[\\[]+"` . I think there no problem with your regex.

Comment: regex is only properly supported in gcc 4.9+

Comment: @AvinashRaj You my friend is the best (can you just post a answer in order to validate it?)

Comment: @nhahtdh i take not on this!